# Determining if an array of numbers contains a specific element within 2D character array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, memory, strcmp

***Overview***
I am currently writing a C program that simulates a bingo checker. In this program, a user enters a 2D Array, a string of numbers, followed another 2D array. All done through standard input.

The first 2D array is the bingo pattern. The 1D array is the numbers called during the game. The second 2D array is the player's actual pattern on their card. The purpose of the program is to determine if their bingo is valid or invalid. A sample input is as follows:

```
1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1

12 20 15 40 45 32 71 07 56 51 36 55 19 10 43 23 70 11 27 60 67 03 72 33 56 09 02

12 29 39 57 61
15 30 45 60 75
07 23 00 46 68
02 18 37 51 70
10 27 32 55 71
```

***Problem***
Since I have to compare the arrays with the strings of numbers, I thought it would be easier to create a third 2D array, named `playerPattern`, which is also filled with ones and zeros. In the final block of code in the snippet below, the program checks if the value in the current position of the player's actual board, `playerBoard`, is within the `numbersCalled` array. If so, it places a 1 in that spot. Then, it will compare the first 2D array, `bingoPattern` with `playerPattern`.

However, in the final for-loop, the if condition is causing the program to halt and throw a signal 11 disruption.

```
if (strcmp(currentArrayElem, currentNumCalled) == 0 {           strcpy(&playerPattern[row][col], "1");
}
```

I can not figure out why the memory allocation is an issue here, as the pointers seem to be set-up correctly.

```
// necessary import statements
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    
    char* bingoPattern[5][5];   // array to store initial bingo pattern (1's and 0's)
    char* playerBoard[5][5];    // array to store player's actual bingo board
    char* playerPattern[5][5];  // array to store player's actual bingo pattern
    char  inputNumString[225];  // undelimited string of numbers for initial standard input
    
    // read-in bingo pattern
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            fscanf(stdin, "%d", &bingoPattern[i][j]); } }
    
    // read-in numbers called
    fgets(inputNumString, 225, stdin);  // skip empty line
    fgets(inputNumString, 225, stdin);  // collect string input
    fgets(inputNumString, 225, stdin);  // skip empty line
    
    char *numbersCalled[75];    // final array of delimited elements
    char singleNumber;  // single string of delimited numbers
    
    inputNumString[strlen(inputNumString + 1)] = 32;
    singleNumber = strtok(inputNumString, " ");

    int numCalledCount = 0; // stores amount of numbers called
    while (singleNumber != NULL) {
        numbersCalled[numCalledCount] = singleNumber;
        numCalledCount = numCalledCount + 1;
        singleNumber = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    
    // read-in player's actual board
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            fscanf(stdin, "%d", &playerBoard[i][j]);
        }
    }
    
    // populate player pattern with zero's
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
           playerPattern[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    
    // create player pattern
    char* currentNumCalled;
    char* currentArrayElem;

    for (int currentNumber = 0; currentNumber < numCalledCount; currentNumber++) {
        
       currentNumCalled = numbersCalled[currentNumber];
       
       for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
           for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
               currentArrayElem = &playerBoard[row][col];
               
               
               if (strcmp(currentArrayElem, currentNumCalled) == 0) {
                   strcpy(&playerPattern[row][col], "1");
               }
           }
       }
    } 
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have three calls to `fgets`, all writing to the same `inputNumString`. Each consecutive call will *overwrite* the contents from the previous call. So what happens is that `inputNumString` will contain the second "empty line".

Comment: Also, `inputNumString[strlen(inputNumString + 1)] = 32` will overwrite the null-terminator, so the string is no longer null-terminated which means you can never pass it to any function relying on the string terminator being there. Your very next call to `strtok` *will* lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Oh and `fscanf(stdin, "%d", &bingoPattern[i][j])`? That's *undefined behavior* as well. The `%d` format is to read `int` values, and its expected argument is `int *`. The type of `&bingoPattern[i][j]` is `char **`. Very much wrong.

Comment: I can make those fixes as there were warnings, but they do not cause the signal 11 error. The error is only thrown when the conditional statement is executed in the code. If that portion is removed, the program executes successfully.

Comment: Both the `fscanf` and `strtok` can lead to crashes. And the `fscanf` problem is with *all* your use of the function and the arrays. And with `strcpy(&playerPattern[row][col], "1")` as well. And the `strcmp` call. You seem to skipped some very important chapters in your text-books when it comes to arrays, pointers, and strings.